# Let $F\leq E \leq K$ fields. If $K/F$ is a finite extension field then $[E:F]\leq [K:F]$ and $[K:E]\leq [K:F]$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $F\leq E \leq K$ fields. If $K/F$ is a finite extension field then $[E:F]\leq [K:F]$ and $[K:E]\leq [K:F]$

My try, how $K/F$ is a extension field then as a $F-$vector space $E$ is a subspace of $K$ and then $\rm{dim}_F E \leq  \rm{dim}_F K$ and then $[E:F]\leq [K:F]$  by definition but for the second part im stuck any hint? im trying not to use that $[K:F]=[K:E][K:F]$

Comment: Hint: Pick an $E$-basis $\{a_1, \dots, a_N\}$ of $K$ and note that this system is linearly independent over $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=[K:E]<\infty$. Then we can pick a basis $\{a_1, \dots, a_N\}$ of $K$ over $E$. If we can show that $\{a_1, \dots, a_N\}$ are linearly independent over $F$ too, then we get $[K:E]=N \leq [K:F]$ (as every linearly independent family can be extended to a basis).

Let us show now that $\{a_1, \dots, a_N\}$ are linearly dependent over $F$. Let $r_1, \dots, r_N \in F $ such that

$$r_1 a_1 + \dots + r_N a_N =0.$$

As $r_j \in F\subseteq E$ and $\{a_1, \dots, a_N\}$ is linearly independent over $E$ we get $r_j=0$ for all $j\in \{1, \dots, N\}$, which means that $\{a_1, \dots, a_N\}$ is linearly independent over $F$.